# What does the saying "like a blind man in a sky light" (כסומא בארובה) indicate?

Tags: words, see-sight-vision-blind, slaughter-shochet-shecht, intent-accident-purposely, allegory-mashal

It seems to me that the Simla Hadasha uses the saying "כסומא בארובה" to mean that it happened by accident.

I do not see what in the simple meaning (as a blind man in a sky light) of the words an accident.

please explain the saying כסומא בארובה

This statement is found in Simla Chadasha [1.19](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=35269&hilite=de1d293c-14e8-4920-9332-e47ad9fddb41&st=%D7%91%D7%90%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%91%D7%94&pgnum=14) and [1.28](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=35269&hilite=de1d293c-14e8-4920-9332-e47ad9fddb41&st=%D7%91%D7%90%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%91%D7%94&pgnum=15).

It is also used at [Baba Basra 12B](http://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=23&daf=12b&format=text) and [Nida 20B](http://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=37&daf=20b&format=text).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The simplest explanation for this concept is

> "Like a blind man (finding) in a trap door (in an attic)"

To expand on that: much like a blind man cannot find his way out of a room without help*, and if he did it by himself it was just pure luck, so too are these שחיטות that came out good -- you can't use these to prove that someone who doesn't know הלכות שחיטה (SC [1:19](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=35269&st=%25u05D1%25u05D0%25u05E8%25u05D5%25u05D1%25u05D4&pgnum=14)) or the חרש (SC [1:28](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=35269&st=%25u05D1%25u05D0%25u05E8%25u05D5%25u05D1%25u05D4&pgnum=15)) can slaughter unsupervised.

The Rashi on the gemara that you linked to ([Bava Basra 12b](http://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=23&daf=12b&format=pdf)) writes:

> לאו טעמא קאמר. במילתיה **וכיון דאמר טעמא אין זה כסומא שמכוון לירד
>   בארובה במקרה בעלמא** אלא סברת הלב היא הבאה לו בנבואה וזכה להסכים להלכה
>   למשה מסיני
>
> [...] since he gave the reason that this is like the "סומא בארובה,"
>   who intends to go down (from the attic) only by chance [...]

( *my translation, of the bold part only* )

---

**An ארובה, literally, is the opening to the attic, or skylight; see, for example, [אהלות ה:ב](http://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%9E%D7%A9%D7%A0%D7%94_%D7%90%D7%94%D7%9C%D7%95%D7%AA_%D7%94#.D7.9E.D7.A9.D7.A0.D7.94_.D7.91). The parable being used here is just like a blind man in an attic, can't get out (through the ארובה) by himself without getting very lucky; so, too, these observed שחיטות may only have been done correctly through "pure blind luck," and cannot be relied on to create a חזקה that they can שחט, so that what they do when unsupervised would be kosher.*

Comment: This is what my rebbi told me, and (at least to me) it makes a lot of sense. I found the Rashi through the gemaras linked to in the question.

Comment: Bartenura on the Mishnah you brought

Comment: רע'ב: ארובה. כמין חלון שבגג הבית שהוא קרקעית העליה:

Comment: Aruba - is the trap door from the attic?

Comment: @hazoriz Yes. I thought it would be pretty obvious just from the wording of the mishna, but that רע"ב certainly helps.

Comment: So the literal translation is as a blind man finds the trap door (wich is hard to find) in the attic?

Comment: @hazoriz Yes, you're right. Will fix that in the answer.

Comment: maybe it is obvious, but i just got it today, a trap door is harder for a blind man to find than a regular door, since to find a regular door he can just walk straight until he hits a wall and then follow it until he finds the door but it is  much harder (almost by accident) for him to find the trap door (whole in the floor in the middle of the room)

Comment: From Artscroll's baba Basra 12b1 translation "as a blind man (finds his way down) through a skylight (I.e. By sheer luck)" it seems that he is jumping down and dose not know if he will land safely.

Comment: @hazoriz Interesting.